# Changing an HTML Element in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I can get an HTML element from my clojurescript page in the REPL:

```
cljs.user=> (.-innerHTML (.getElementById js/document "app"))
"This is clojure"
```

But how do i change this element to for example:
"This is awesome clojure"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Clojurescript to interact with the html DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228474/how-can-i-use-clojurescript-to-interact-with-the-html-dom)

Answer (score 1):

You can mutate this element like so...

`(set! (.-innerHTML (.getElementById js/document "app")) "This is awesome ClojureScript")`

And please be aware that you could also say...

`(set! (.. js/document (getElementById "app") -innerHTML) "This is awesome ClojureScript")`

...in case that is more attractive to you. Or you could say...

`(->> "This is awesome ClojureScript" (set! (.. js/document (getElementById "app") -innerHTML)))`

...or...

`(let [app-element (js/document.getElementById "app")] (set! (.-innerHTML app-element) "This is awesome ClojureScript"))`

Blessings,
Raphael